# Detect if user is on the specific page in WordPress

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have my WordPress plugin, it does not use post types so I cannot make use of wp_check_post_lock and similar.

I have plugin menu which leads to (for example):

```
http://localhost/xampp/wp/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my_playlist_manager
```

Then it can go further:

```
http://localhost/xampp/wp/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my_playlist_manager&action=edit_playlist&playlist_id=14
```

Admin can view / edit all playlists, while user can see only his playlists. Data is saved in wpdb in custom tables.

**What I dont want to happen is user and admin possibly editing same playlist.**

Is there an easy and effective way to achieve this?  For example, I could hide buttons for editing playlist for user if admin is editing the same, but how would I know this?

Comment: So your main challenge is to avoid two persons editing the same playlist at the same time? To avoid one change overwriting the changes of the other?

Comment: Strange, there was an answer to this question from some person, but now its missing. Yes, this is my goal. I realize it might need to include some ajax or similar because you can really detect when the page is closed.

Comment: It sounds simple, set column in table as edited when some user enters edit playlist page, but how to know when this ends. User can close browser, user can leave this page opened "forever" without actually editing anything... (maybe there are more cases)